# Undefined control sequence error on empty line

Tags: errors

This is the start of my document:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,11pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}
```

I'm getting an error on the empty line before \begin{document} which says "Undefined control sequence" and "Missing number, treated as zero".

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Basically this is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided: you are using `minimal` as a class, and it was never intended for use beyond certain low-level tests. The error isn't caused by the blank line but by `sestspace` looking for something that's not there!